# User defined structure type in TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have found some code that does what I am looking for, but in `Oracle SQL`. Is it possible to do the same in `SSMS`? Check out the code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
TYPE obj_address_num AS OBJECT
( street varchar2(50),
numb number,
additionalInfo VARCHAR2(10),
MEMBER FUNCTION get_street RETURN varchar2,
MEMBER FUNCTION get_numb RETURN number,
MEMBER FUNCTION get_aditionalInfo RETURN varchar2
)
INSTANTIABLE NOT FINAL;
CREATE OR REPLACE
TYPE BODY obj_address_numb AS
MEMBER FUNCTION get_street RETURN varchar2 IS
BEGIN
RETURN SELF.street;
END;
MEMBER FUNCTION get_numb RETURN number IS
BEGIN
RETURN SELF.numb;
END;
MEMBER FUNCTION get_additionalInfo RETURN varchar2 IS
BEGIN
RETURN SELF.additionalInfo;
END;
END;
```

I guess this could be done through some `.Net` language, but is it possible to type this code just by using `TSQL`?

Comment: Check the link for more detail https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-type-transact-sql

Comment: Not in T-SQL. SQL Server is optimized as a relational rather than object database so you'll need to step into the SQLCLR world for [user-defined types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-user-defined-types/clr-user-defined-types) that represent structures.